# Given That .. Compute ... Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Given That  $\left| \begin{matrix} 
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{matrix} \right| = \frac{1}{2}$, compute $\left| \begin{matrix} 
b + 3a & e + 3d & h + 3g \\
a & d & g \\
-2c & -2f & -2i
\end{matrix} \right|$

Above is two $3 \times 3$ matrices, I would really like some help with this problem I got wrong on a test. Whats the answer and how did you get to your solution?

Comment: Did you show your work? Were there any comments on the test indicating where you went wrong?

Comment: no comments were made. I blanked

Comment: Are you sure the second matrix is written correctly?

Comment: Ok please refresh your screen I updated it. There were a few errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left| \begin{matrix} 
b + 3a & e + 3d & h + 3g \\
a & d & g \\
-2c & -2f & -2i
\end{matrix} \right|$$

$$= -2\left| \begin{matrix} 
b + 3a & e + 3d & h + 3g \\
a & d & g \\
c & f & i
\end{matrix} \right|$$

$$= -2\left| \begin{matrix} 
b  & e  & h  \\
a & d & g \\
c & f & i
\end{matrix} \right|$$

$$= +2\left| \begin{matrix} 
a & d & g \\
b & e & h \\
c & f & i
\end{matrix} \right|$$

$$= 2\left| \begin{matrix} 
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i
\end{matrix} \right|$$

$$ = 2 \cdot {1 \over 2} = 1$$

- Line $1\to 2$: multiplying a row by a constant multiplies the determinant by that constant
- Line $2 \to 3$: adding a multiple of a row to another row leaves the determinant unchanged
- Line $3 \to 4$: swapping two adjacent rows swaps the sign of the determinant
- Line $4 \to 5$: $\det A = \det A^T$

Comment: I would like to thank you for your time. Yes I have a few questions. How did you go from step 1 to step 2? What method are you using to solve this problem?

Comment: See the comments I just added. Make sense?

Comment: Ok so your taking the determinants... the way I learned it was to use a combination of row reduction techniques and Gaussian Elimination. I'm sorry understanding your method.

Comment: I suspect the intent is not to calculate this determinant from first principles. Rather, it is almost certainly the case that you should use the four properties of determinants I have cited here. So I recommend double checking your lecture notes and/or assignments for similar questions which use these properties. If after that search you come up blank then ask your tutor/TA/lecturer/professor what the intended method of solution was.

Comment: OOOO.. Ok I see what you are saying. Thank you for all your time :)